# Shift elements in 2D ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, 2d, jlabel

I have 2D `ArrayList` which was filled with elements (objects which contain images etc.) so the 2D array was full. After calling removing functions my array looks like the picture on the left side; on the right side you can see the desired result. Could someone please give me the idea how to reorganize my array as you can see on the picture?

[image: the desired result]

The idea was to go from to bottom to top. If I find the gap (the gap means that I set the background of element to `null`, respectively, `imageIcon` is set to `null`) I will switch it for the previous element. And because I have switched it I have to do it for the whole column. Problem is, when they are 2 or more gaps and also, this algorithm does nothing.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        for (int j = 7; j > 0; j--) {
            Item currentItem = this.elements.get(j).get(i).getItem();

            if (currentItem.getBack().getIcon() == null) {
                int count = j;

                while (count > 1) {
                    Position temp = this.elements.get(count).get(i);
                    Position zero = this.elements.get(count).get(i);
                    Position previous = this.elements.get(count - 1).get(i);
                    zero = previous;
                    previous = temp;

                    count--;

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

The arrayed data size is limited to 10x8 because of my gameboard panel. The items in array are not distinguishable, they only have different backgrounds (type of `JLabel` component). The items have to "fall from top to down".

PS: I am creating a clone of Bejeweled

[image: shot1]

[image: shot2]

Comment: Agree with @khelwood. Without your code, it's anyone's guess what you could be doing wrong.

Comment: Also, your link is not to an image, and so we can't help you place your picture. Only post links to actual images.

Comment: sorry guys, now it should be fixed :)

Comment: @Arsiwaldi you can think that each column is an array of items with two states - 1 (not null) and 0 (null). And what you need is just to sort these items to have all the 1 first and all the 0 next. Just implement something like bubble sort. You're just one step away from it.

Comment: `The reason why I am using ArrayList is simple,`... yeah? `I have to use it.` ? Nope, that's **not** a reasonable reason. `I assume that use of "bubble sort" in this case is impossible.` - you assume wrong. Also, your question has already been answered. If you don't have the necessary coding skills to reimplement an algo given to you, you're not going to be able to solve your task anyway. Also, `Probably because the items in array are not somehow distinguishable they have got only the different background` means you're mixing your domain logic with GUI logic, breaking good coding rules direly.

Comment: @vaxquis +1 for the mixing domain logic and GUI logic remark

Comment: Thank you guys, the idea of bubbleSort was ideal. I did some changes in my code. Applied your idea and it seems it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have shown in the pictures, you want the column's elements to be "dropped to bottom"? If that is the case, you should probably use a regular 2D array instead of `ArrayList`, with an array for each of your *columns*, and assume the bottom is indexed `0` - why? because `ArrayList` doesn't have fixed size, and your problem statement shows you want the container to be of fixed size. The solution would then be (roughly, because you shown only a part of your code, not a SSCCE):

```
//Item[][] items;
for( Item[] arr : items )
  for( int i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i-- )
    if ( arr[i] == null ) // or arr[i].getBack().getIcon() == null or whatever
      for( int j = i; j < arr.length - 1; j++ )
        arr[j] = arr[j+1];
```

This is a crude bubble sort, suitable for small arrays. There are other solutions possible (as this is a sorting problem by itself - you may look up qsort for this), but this one is arguably the simplest.

Note: You may implement the very same solution for `ArrayList`s, yet I strongly advocate against it. Using nested `ArrayList`s to mimic multi-dim arrays is seldom a good idea - it'll create the arrays anyway, but you'll get a large overhead, making the code both slower and less readable - anyway you can do so by replacing `[]`s with `get()`/`set()` etc.

For the sake of reference:

```
//ArrayList<ArrayList<Item>> items;
//int columnHeight;
for( ArrayList<Item> arr : items )
  for( int i = columnHeight - 2; i >= 0; i-- )
    if ( arr.get(i) == null ) //or arr.get(i).getIcon()==null or whatever
      for( int j = i; j < columnHeight - 1; j++ )
        arr.set(j, arr.get(j+1));
```

or simply, by providing a comparator:

```
//ArrayList<ArrayList<Item>> items;
//int columnHeight;
for( ArrayList<Item> arr : items )
  Collections.sort(arr, new Comparator<Item>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item i1, Item i2) {
        return ...; // place the sorting rule here
    }
  });
```

For more info, see docs for [Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) & [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Also, if this is indeed for Bejewelled clone - you may consider doing the "dropping" by doing an iteration dropping *all* jewels with an empty field beneath by one step, counting the amount of dropped jewels, and repeating this iteration till the amount of drops == 0. That's the algo I used in my clone in the days of the past.

Answer (score -1):

As @vaxquis has already mentioned, it's better to rewrite your code in some more elegant way.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    // Perfoming bubble sort for each column
    boolean swapped = true;
    for(int j = 6; j > 0 && swapped; j--) {
        swapped = false;

        for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
            Item currentItem =  this.elements.get(k).get(i).getItem();
            Item nextItem    =  this.elements.get(k+1).get(i).getItem();

            if (currentItem.getBack().getIcon() != nextItem.getBack().getIcon()) {
                swap(currentItem, nextItem);   // implement this yourself
                swapped = true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Besides the algorithm issues addressed by the other answers, your main problem is that you never change anything in the arrays. The following code just moves some values between local variables:

```
Position temp = this.elements.get(count).get(i);
Position zero = this.elements.get(count).get(i);
Position previous = this.elements.get(count - 1).get(i);
zero = previous;
previous = temp;
```

You probably have a `setItem()` method to set things back into a `Position` object? Then a swap would be:

```
Position current = this.elements.get(count).get(i);
Position previous = this.elements.get(count - 1).get(i);
Item temp = current.getItem();
current.setItem(previous.getItem();
previous.setItem(temp);
```